# css redirect right click/open link in new tab?

Tags: html, css

is there anyway to redirect the image paths on a page with css? 
When you right click & open link in new tab comes up can you redirect a viewer to an alternative link?

Comment: Not very clear… You mean having the source of the images in a different path than the site? or different domain?

Comment: a different path of the site

Comment: Do you mean the path to the image location, or the path to the link target when the image is a link?

Comment: That is possible for the source of the images, not for the link of the page, CSS deals with the rendered output not page/server processing!

Comment: exmpl. if you right click an image and the option (open link in new tab) it will take you to a blank page with the image. is it possible? for me to reroute that image to go back...lets say to the homepage , once open link in new tab is clicked?

Comment: When right clicking and viewing the image, it is dealt with the browser not the scripting in your site (unless maybe with javascript)

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Really, you shouldn't. But if you are desperate, you could fiddle around with PHP. If you are interested in that, let me know.

Comment: yes i am interested in that too? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

This is something you mentioned. 
when you right click on image and click on new tab then it will take you to 'NewLink'

```
<a href='NewLink'> <img src='imagelocation'> </a>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS affects only the style of the page, you should use .htaccess or whatever web server redirects to handle such issue.